# filtering in a Firestore query based on the length of the ID

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I created an app that uses `firestore` as its main database.

In the database, I have a collection called Books. Inside this collection, there are documents where the id of them are created in a different way. For one type the id has 12 digits in it, and the other type has like 20.

For example:

[image]

Now, inside each of these documents I have a field called id that follows the same logic of 12 or 20 digits.

How can I query only the documents that have an ID of 20 digits for example?

I tried something like this but didnt work:

```
db.collection( "Books" ).whereGreaterThan( "id", 15 ).limit(20).get()
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't know of any Firestore query filters that are based on the *length* of the ID. Is there any reason you don't want to have the "type of book" as a separate field? It feels like that would be clearer in intent as well as more practical to filter on.

Comment: (I also suggest you edit your title - "getting a Firestore document based on ID" sounds like a "fetch by ID" which is definitely supported - what you're asking about is "filtering in a Firestore query based on the length of the ID" which is quite different. I guess it's the ambiguity of "based on".)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will be honest that since I managed to solve all my problems so far only by checking the length differences I didn't think to add the type as a field value. But I guess that if there is no option to do so I will need to add as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support queries like this at all.

If you want to filter on the length of the document ID, you would have to store that number as a field in the document, then use a normal where clause to find it.  Without that numeric field in place, what you're trying to do isn't possible.